# First element static on a drag & drop li list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using the [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) jquery lib. It works really good. I'm trying right now to have the first element of the li list static, I want this first element not to be move from the first place.  Not quite sure how to do this.

This is the code for sorting.

A small demo of how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/DiegoTc/vK588/

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="sortable">
    <li id="pTabP" class="active">First</li>
    <li id="pTabP2" class="active">Second</li>
    <li id="pTabP3" class="active">Third</li>
</ul>

$(function() {
 $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
 $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items) said you can decide which element you do not want to move, base in your markup you could you use the id of the first element and do something like

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
     items: "li:not(#pTabP)"
});
```

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/vK588/1/)

Answer (score 1):

From the docs : http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items

```
$(function() {

    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        items: "li:not(#pTabP)"
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();

});
```